# Sidebar elements pushed outside the sidebar when padding added

Tags: reactjs

Note: becasue I am a new user, I cannot embed photos yet. The photos are in links generated by Stack overflow below.

The below is the design I am trying to achieve,

[image]

However, the below is currently what is happening

[image]

As you can see, the sidebar list is appearing to go outside the sidebar itself when the padding is added.

How can I manipulate my CSS to alter?

```
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

  }

.Sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    width: 250px;
    background-color: white;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    padding-left: 15px;

    


  }

  .SidebarList {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 2px #FD954E;
    border-right: 1px solid;

  }

  .SidebarList .row {
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: white;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0%;
      display: flex;
      color: #A7ACB6;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;

  }

.SidebarList .row:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #E7E7E7  ;
}

.SidebarList #active {
  background-color: white;
  color: #FD954E
}

  .row #icon {
    flex: 30%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
  }

  .row #title {
    flex: 70%;
  }

.Logo {
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-top: 25px;

}
```

Comment: Your `padding-left` is adding additional width to the sidebar. Use `box-sizing: border-box` to ensure that padding is included in the width calculations.

Comment: @Terry can you post answer? Still does not seem to be working...

Comment: Nevermind! Was making a silly error